# Selenium - Click Link where Text is IMG

Tags: python, image, xpath, selenium

I am trying to click on a "next" page link on a page.  The html is for the link is:

```
<a href="http://www.lewisbrisbois.com/attorneys/search/-/eyJjb2xsZWN0aW9uIjoiYXR0b3JuZXlzIiwicmVzdWx0X3BhZ2UiOiJhdHRvcm5leXNcL3NlYXJjaFwvLSIsInNlYXJjaF9tb2RlIjoiYWxsIiwic2l0ZSI6ImRlZmF1bHRfc2l0ZSJ9/P30"><img src="/assets/images/icons/arrow-orange-right.png" alt="Picture" /></a>
```

The img is an orange arrow.  The img doesnt change on subsequent pages, but the link does.  So I would like to select the link using the img, instead of using the link itself (that way I will not have to use 30 different xpath's, instead I can use only one).

The page where this exists is: http://www.lewisbrisbois.com/attorneys/search/-/eyJjb2xsZWN0aW9uIjoiYXR0b3JuZXlzIiwicmVzdWx0X3BhZ2UiOiJhdHRvcm5leXNcL3NlYXJjaFwvLSIsInNlYXJjaF9tb2RlIjoiYWxsIiwic2l0ZSI6ImRlZmF1bHRfc2l0ZSJ9

Is there a way to do this in selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `img` by partial src (the filename), then go to its parent `a` tag.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'arrow-orange-right.png')]/parent::a")
```

Equivalent xpaths (first one find the parent a, the second go to parent element directly):

```
//img[contains(@src, 'arrow-orange-right.png')]/parent::a
//img[contains(@src, 'arrow-orange-right.png')]/..
```

If the partial src is not unique, you may want to use full path `/assets/images/icons/arrow-orange-right.png`.

```
//img[@src='/assets/images/icons/arrow-orange-right.png']/..
```